# I want to show first 2 objects in my django template but it shows me this error

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates, slice

```
{% for post in object_list|slice : "2" %}
<div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-round w3-margin"><br>
    <img src="/w3images/avatar5.png" alt="Avatar" class="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:60px">
    <span class="w3-right w3-opacity">{{post.date}}</span>
    <h4>{{ post.author.username }}</h4><br>
    <hr class="w3-clear">
    <p>{{post.text}}</p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The error shown is

> **'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for post in object_list|slice : "2"**

The code works when I remove slice:2. if I add again it will throw error as above.

Comment: What if you remove the spacing, so `slice:"2"` instead of `slice : "2"`?

Comment: try to add `slice:":2"` after slice

Comment: After all what you here do is mixing two grammars, and as a result, the parser gets confused.

Comment: Thank you Willem and Manoj for your answers. Removing the spaces made it work for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be [note the extra **:** ]

```
{% for post in object_list|slice : ":2" %}
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)